# Laravel: columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to call this query instead of ID when updating a record, but im getting an error saying **columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in**

```
$user = Attendances::find(DB::raw('concat (firstname, " ",lastname)'), 'like', Input::get('student_name'))->where('section_name', 'like', Input::get('section_name'))->where('teacher_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->where('subject_code', 'like', Input::get('subject_code'));
```

Pleae help :(

Comment: return `DB::getQueryLog();` and see what you have in your query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first method should be `where()` as well, because `find()` only works with primary keys. Also at the end should call `get()` or `first()` to execute the query:

```
$user = Attendances::where(DB::raw('concat (firstname, " ",lastname)'), 'like', Input::get('student_name'))
       ->where('section_name', 'like', Input::get('section_name'))
       ->where('teacher_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
       ->where('subject_code', 'like', Input::get('subject_code'))
       ->first();
```